# Application Crashing:A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:[libsystem_platform.dylib+0x15d2] _platform_strlen+0x12

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I am running Sencha Cmd v6.7.0.63 and while running "Sencha app watch" the app is crashing with below error. I am running the app on Mac OS.

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff2039c5d2, pid=2170, tid=26375
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [libsystem_platform.dylib+0x15d2]  _platform_strlen+0x12

Comment: Appreciate if anyone can give some suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: We have found a work around for this issue. I am using Mac OS 11.4 and it seems to be an issue with the environment. The app crashes during the build when the internet is turned ON on the machine. When the internet is off during the build process, the build is successful and the app launches. It is worth noting that this is a work around and would be keen to know the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar error during development.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000010c1a4b52, pid=89645, tid=0x0000000000003e07
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_352) (build 1.8.0_352-bre_2022_12_13_23_07-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.352-b00 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
```

The solution which worked for me was to install Java 8 from Oracle corporation instead of Open JDK 8 and point to Java8 JDK in my project structure.

Once done do a

> mvn clean install -U

and you should be good to go.